# I need to find a given word in a string of names

Tags: python-3.x, find-occurrences

`sudo:x:27:mike,david,dash,bart,pablo,jack`. This string contains a few names that are separated by only camas. If I say I want to find out if mike is in the string, I want my program to look for that given name. But if I ask if "pa" is in the string, the program will say that "pa" is in the string, even though "pa" is not a name, rather part of a name. How do I separate each name or even better, set it up into a sort of list so that it is easier to identify if a given name is in the group?

This is what my program looks so far:

```
import re

user = str(input("What user are you looking for?\n"))

txt = open("group.txt", "r")

for line in txt:
    if re.match("(.*)sudo(.*)", line):
        if <!where I need the code!>:
            print(user + " is a sudoer")
            break
        else:
            print(user + " is not a sudoer")
            break
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my environment, the following was working as expected:

```
    import re

    user = str(input("What user are you looking for?\n"))

    txt = open("group.txt", "r")

    for line in txt:
        if re.match("(.*)sudo(.*)", line):
            if re.match("sudo.+(:|,)%s(,|$)" % user, line):
                print(user + " is a sudoer")
                break
            else:
                print(user + " is not a sudoer")
                break
```

Please note that the regular expression is case-sensitive, e.g. it won't find *Mike* if you specified his name in capitalized form as user input.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. I had a similar solution to yours but it did not fully fix it.

Answer (score 0):

If `input` is the string you mentioned, and `name` is the name you're looking for:

```
name in input.rpartition(':')[2].split(',')
```

will return the boolean you're looking for.

Comment: It works, but it won’t recognize that the last name is in the string. If I input jack, it will tell me that jack it not in the group.

Comment: That doesn't sound right. It works for me:
`>>> input = "sudo:x:27:mike,david,dash,bart,pablo,jack"`
`>>> "jack" in input.rpartition(':')[2].split(',')`
`True`

Comment: Yes, it works. But when I put it into an if statement, it did not recognize that it was in the sudo group.

Comment: This is because of how you're iterating over it. When you iterate over a file as you did with a for loop, the newlines are preserved. You *could* fix this by changing it to `input.rpartition(':')[2].strip().split(',')` (notice the added call to strip()), but le_affan's solution which uses re is better.